# Spaces in text stored as underscore in MySQL

Tags: mysql, encoding

I am storing text in MySQL by sending a request to a url with a function.

The url is encoded with %20 as spaces which is all very well but when it is stored in MySQL the spaces are replaced with underscore _ .

This is a sentence -> This_is_a_sentence.

Is there a way of avoiding this issue?

This is the code:

```
    function new_experiment_reply($thread_title = '', $raven_thread_id = '', $text = '', $forum_url = '', $raven_forum_id = '')
{
    $email = $this->session->userdata('email');
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM fn_users WHERE email='" . $email . "'");
    $fn_user_id = $query->first_row()->id;
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT username FROM forum_users WHERE fn_user_id='" . $fn_user_id . "' AND raven_forum_id='" . $raven_forum_id . "'");
    $username = $query->first_row()->username;
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i");
    $query = $this->db->query('INSERT INTO promo_replies(thread_title, raven_thread_id, text, forum_url, raven_forum_id, date, fn_user_id, username) VALUES("'. $thread_title .'", "'. $raven_thread_id .'", "'. $text .'", "'. $forum_url . '", "'. $raven_forum_id . '", "'. $date . '", "'. $fn_user_id . '", "'. $username . '") ');
}
```

The inserted value of variables (as they are seen in Fiddler and as they should be):

```
$thread_title= Facebook%20vs%20Google
$raven_thread_id = 123441
$text = This%20is%20a%20sentence
$forum_url = domain.com
$raven_forum_id = 32
```

After echoing the query I got the following results:

```
INSERT INTO promo_replies
    (thread_title, raven_thread_id, text, forum_url, raven_forum_id, date, fn_user_id, username) 
VALUES
    ("Facebook_vs_Google", "123441", "This_is_a_sentence", "domain_com", "32", "2012-09-06 06:04", "8", "usssaa")
```

I am prepared to get bashed regarding the code so no worries there.

Comment: Could you provide the function itself?

Comment: That's not how it behaves by default, it's something *you* do.

Comment: I added the function itself! Appreciate your time.

Comment: And the value of `$thread_title` (or other relevant variables) right before you insert them into the database is?

Comment: Do `echo 'INSERT INTO promo_replies(thread_title, raven_thread_id, text, forum_url, raven_forum_id, date, fn_user_id, username) VALUES("'. $thread_title .'", "'. $raven_thread_id .'", "'. $text .'", "'. $forum_url . '", "'. $raven_forum_id . '", "'. $date . '", "'. $fn_user_id . '", "'. $username . '") ';` just after the last line of your function, to check what is the query.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, added the values of the variables now.

Comment: Inserted the additional information, and it shows the same result that is stored in mysql.